# ActiveMQ Stomp Python client listener creating extraneous consumers

Tags: python, queue, activemq-classic, listener, stomp

We're building a queuing system in Python that involves a series of microservices that subscribe to a queue. After each microservice processes a message, it creates the next message in the queue as the process moves along in the workflow.

All microservices are using the python stomp package version `stomp==7.0.0`. The microservices all use the same wrapper code in a custom package we've built for the purpose of connecting and subscribing.

The microservices are all running in a docker swarm, and each microservice has multiple replicas, in this case 4 replicas per microservice.

**Issue:**

We would expect *one* instance of a microservice to create *one* listener (consumer) only. So we would expect that one microservice with 4 replicas to have 4 consumers only.

However, what we're seeing is the number of consumers increasing and decreasing intermittently as messages are being processed in the queue.

So one microservice with 4 replicas starts with 4 consumers as expected, but then increases to 5 and then more and more as time goes on, in some cases 10 consumers or more. Also in some cases consumers are dropping off entirely, going down to 3 and then eventually down to 0 and then the entire pipeline seems to get stalled.

The extraneous consumers seem to cause performance and stability issues in the pipeline.

**Notes**

We set the container hostname as the client_id for each connection to track which consumers are being created on each host. The extra consumers have the same client_ids as the ones already connected. This is probably a key fact, since by all accounts that shouldn’t be possible.

**Questions**

- Are our expectations correct that one instance of a microservice would have one consumer only?
- What could be causing the extraneous consumers to be created?
- What could be causing consumers to be lost?

**Code**

```
_client_id = f"mqutils_listener_{os.getenv('HOSTNAME')}"

def initialize_mqlistener():
    if _failback_host and _failback_port:
        print('failback host and port in use')
        conn = stomp.Connection([(_host, _port),(_failback_host, _failback_port)], heartbeats=(40000, 40000), keepalive=True)
    else:
        print('failback host and port not in use')
        conn = stomp.Connection([(_host, _port)], heartbeats=(40000, 40000), keepalive=True)
    conn.set_listener('', MqListener(conn))
    connect_and_subscribe(conn)
    # http_clients://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/issues/206
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        if not conn.is_connected():
            print('Disconnected in loop, reconnecting')
            connect_and_subscribe(conn)


def connect_and_subscribe(conn, queue=_queue, sub_id=_sub_id):
    print(_hostname_prefix + "************************ MQUTILS MQLISTENER - CONNECT_AND_SUBSCRIBE *******************************")
    global _reconnect_attempts
    _reconnect_attempts = _reconnect_attempts + 1
    if _reconnect_attempts <= _max_attempts:
        # TODO: Retry timer with exponential backoff
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            if not os.getenv('MQ_DISABLE_SSL'):
                if _failback_host and _failback_port:
                    conn.set_ssl([(_host, _port),(_failback_host, _failback_port)])
                else:
                    conn.set_ssl([(_host, _port)])
            if not conn.is_connected():
                conn.connect(_user, _password, headers={'client-id': _client_id}, wait=True)
                print(f'{_hostname_prefix}connect_and_subscribe connecting {queue} to with connection id {sub_id} reconnect attempts: {_reconnect_attempts}', flush=True)
            else:
                print(f'{_hostname_prefix}connect_and_subscibe already connected {queue} to with connection id {sub_id} reconnect attempts {_reconnect_attempts}', flush=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(_hostname_prefix + 'Exception on disconnect. reconnecting...')
            print(_hostname_prefix + traceback.format_exc())
            connect_and_subscribe(conn)
        else:
            conn.subscribe(destination=queue, id=sub_id, ack='client-individual')
            _reconnect_attempts = 0
    else:
        print('{}Maximum reconnect attempts reached for this connection. reconnect attempts: {}'.format(_hostname_prefix, _reconnect_attempts), flush=True)
```

**Logs**

```
received an error "javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: mps-qa - Client: mqutils_listener_7b69983dd500 already connected from tcp://redacted

2022-09-07 14:44:04,030 INFO exited: queuelistener (terminated by SIGABRT; not expected)
2022-09-07 14:44:04,049 INFO spawned: 'queuelistener' with pid 6238
2022-09-07 14:44:05,618 INFO success: queuelistener entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-09-07 14:44:15,334 INFO exited: queuelistener (terminated by SIGABRT; not expected)
2022-09-07 14:44:16,367 INFO spawned: 'queuelistener' with pid 6329
2022-09-07 14:44:17,941 INFO success: queuelistener entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-09-07 14:44:20,143 INFO exited: queuelistener (terminated by SIGABRT; not expected)
2022-09-07 14:44:20,164 INFO spawned: 'queuelistener' with pid 6348
2022-09-07 14:44:21,734 INFO success: queuelistener entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-09-07 14:44:27,280 INFO exited: queuelistener (terminated by SIGABRT; not expected)
2022-09-07 14:44:28,313 INFO spawned: 'queuelistener' with pid 6386
```

Comment: Instead of pasting your actual application code can you instead paste the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem (i.e. a full Python app that I could run and see the same behavior)?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is resource leak in your code. The resource leaking is the consumer subscription (aka queuelistener).

To fix this, you need to unsubscribe and/or close the connection on errors and before you attempt to create a new subscription with the same client id and sub id.

ref: http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html#establishing-a-connection